# How can one cache Oauth2 tokens using Spring Security and WebClient?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux

How can configure refresh token requests and caching of Oauth2 tokens using Spring Security, WebClient and Spring Boot 3.1.3?

I would like to configure a service with the following flow:

1. polls messages from a queue (i.e. the flow is not a result of an incoming http request)
2. does some processing
3. requests an Oauth2 token from an authentication server
4. post the processed data together with the token using `WebClient` to a third party API that uses Oauth2 for authentication
5. re-use the same token for subsequent requests for the duration of the token validity

The flow is working up until step 4. The application successfully makes Oauth authentication request, receives a token and posts the processed data to the third party API with the token added as a `Bearer` token to the `Authorization` header. However, it seems like step 5 is missing as additional authentication requests are made to the authentication server for *every* request, despite that the token suggests that it is valid for one hour.

What is the appropriate way of configuring Spring Security and/or WebClient so that valid tokens are cached and refresh token requests are issued to the authentication server when the existing token is about to expire?

This is what I currently have:

**Configuration Class**

```java
package com.company.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {
    private static final String REMOTE_SERVER_URL = "https://www.remote.com";
    private static final String OAUTH_CLIENT_REGISTRATION = "example";

    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .authorizationCode()
                        .refreshToken()
                        .clientCredentials()
                        .build();

        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient httpClient(
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(OAUTH_CLIENT_REGISTRATION);

        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth2Client)
                .baseUrl(REMOTE_SERVER_URL)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Request Service**

```java
package com.company.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.ACCEPT;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@Service
public class RequestService {
    private static final String SERVER_ENDPOINT = "/endpoint";
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public RequestService(WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    public Mono<ResponseObject> makeRequest(Mono<RequestObject> requestObject) {
        return requestObject.flatMap(req -> this.webClient
                .post()
                .uri(SERVER_ENDPOINT)
                .header(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .bodyValue(requestObject)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ResponseObject.class));
    }
}
```

**application.yaml**

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          example:
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-id: ${client-id}
            client-secret: ${client-secret}
            scope: api://${app-id}/.default
        provider:
          example:
            token-uri: https://example.oauth.server.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Dependencies**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>webclient</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Update 1**

What I see is that an authentication request is made to the authentication server before every request to the third party API:

[image: what I see]

What I would like os that a single authentication request is made before the first request with the third party API. The token should be cached and re-used for every subsequent request with the third party API as long as it is valid:

[image: what I would like to see]

**Update 2**

The token validity period is one hour. I know this that the response authentication server has the following content:

```json
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "ext_expires_in": 3599,
  "access_token": [token]
}
```

The `[token]` is a JWT token and when analysed using https://jwt.io it has (among other things) an `exp` field with an epoch timestamp one hour after the authentication request was made.

**Update 3**

Looking through the JavaDoc I found this code snippet in the [ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction#oauth2AuthorizedClient()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.1.3/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/reactive/function/client/ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.html#oauth2AuthorizedClient(org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient)):

```java
 WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .filter(new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager))
    .build();
 Mono<String> response = webClient
    .get()
    .uri(uri)
    .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))
    // ...
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

One thing that is missing from my current configuration is the `.attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))` part. Is this relevant? If so, from where do I get the `authorizedClient`?

Comment: Have you confirmed that a new `httpClient` or `authorizedClientManager` is not being created everytime due to the service lifetime?

Comment: Yes, since the are being created as Spring `@Bean`s, those objects will be created as singletons when the application starts.

Comment: OK great. And what requests are made? Are they auth code flow or client credentials requests? New tokens are definitely being generated?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary please see the sequence diagrams that I have added to the question

Comment: Thank you, great diagram software btw - curious what application it is! That aside, it looks you're using the client creds flow here. Do just this and see if it works - if not, still update your question with it `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().clientCredentials().build();`

Comment: Spring Security caches the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` (which contains the `access_token`) with the `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService` for you. Are you sure the tokens you receive do not expire quickly?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I tried to remove the `.authorizationCode().refreshToken()` from the `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder`, but the behavior is unchanged. The sequence diagrams were generated by using [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram).

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Yes I thought that Spring Security would have in memory caching enabled by default. Please see my second updated above for details about the token expiration.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Please also see my update about not currently having configured the `.attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))` method call. Is that relevant? Where do I find the `authorizedClient`?

Comment: Information is available in [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/client/authorized-clients.html). See [defaulting the authorized client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/client/authorized-clients.html#_defaulting_the_authorized_client). It might be easier to provide a minimal sample and I can explore it further.

Answer (score -1):

The appropriate way, is to store it in the database, same as it is done with the users and roles/permissions with Spring security. The only difference is that, you to update it, when it's expired.

Besides, in your code there are few things you need to take into consideration.

You are using refresh token, which means once you have the first token, the refresh token is used to extend the validity of the previous token, without the need to issue a new one.

You are also using authorization code grant type for refresh token, which means it follows a whole process, which is used with front application user oriented, therefore it makes sense to have refresh token.

If the grant type was client credentials, then there will not be any need to have refresh token, but to just fire a request each time with client_id and client_secret to get the new bearer token.

What i would recommend, is for you to first check the difference between oAuth grant types, as for your question, you can store them in a h2 or even persist them in mysql databse, once a token is expired, you can set it as expired.

Then the token value, should be in an Authorization header appended with a prefix depending on which type of token, i.e

> Authorization Bearer {token-value}

.

Comment: Ok, so there is no need of a request token. I would expect that Spring Security would support caching of valid tokens given the correct configuration? What would such configuration look like?

Comment: There is no need for a database here, as JWTs are stateless and store expiry time in the `exp` claim. Though the point about the grant types are correct, this answer doesn't actually answer the question and is incorrect in that regard.

Comment: There is no mention of JWT tokens here, besides, he is interested in caching oAuth token and if i am not mistaken, it's more likely a Bearer token. I mentioned h2 database, which can be used for caching tokens. There is difference between, JWT and Bearer tokens.  And for JWTs, even the algorithm of encryption is mentioned in the header, and holds also other info other than exp.

As for the database, it can be used, since spring security also uses a database to store permissions and roles in it, so i don't see the issue in taking advantage of it.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, what I would like to know is how the Spring Security and / or WebClient configuration code snippets in my question should be modified to enable caching (in H2, in memory cache or by other means)?

Comment: You can use the DB but there is no reason why it can't be cached in memory. The issue here is why it's not being cached, not the location of the cache.

Comment: `The appropriate way, is to store it in the database` why would this be the appropriate way? when in memory caching is faster, a lot faster and if the tokens are short lived there is no reason at all to have persistent storage.